# Postgres cursor is not taking multiple parameters

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I have created a procedure, and inside the procedure I have created a parameterized cursor to which I am passing parameters. The Cursor query has two parameters: one parameter of the procedure and the other is the parameter of the cursor.

When I am opening the cursor with the parameter of the cursor, it is not taking the value of the procedure parameter. When I am creating a cursor with no parameter, it is taking the parameter of the procedure.

See the example below: `c2` opens just fine and inserts data into `v_text`, but when I am trying to open `c9` it gives me the error

```
ERROR:  column "p_plan_version_id" does not exist
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pos.plan_version_id"
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_file(IN p_plan_version_id NUMERIC) LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    DECLARE
        v_text text;
        j record;
        l record;
        c2 CURSOR FOR
            SELECT pq.product_code,
                   SUM(quantity) quantity
            FROM product_quantity pq,
                 products         ep
            WHERE pq.plan_version_id = p_plan_version_id
            --and pipeline_id  =1
              AND     pq.product_code = ep.product_code
            GROUP BY product_code;

        C9 CURSOR (p_product_code VARCHAR) IS
            SELECT product_code ,
                   terminal_code,
                   quantity
            FROM product_stock pos
            WHERE pos.plan_version_id = p_plan_version_id
              AND pos.product_code    = p_product_code;

    BEGIN
        OPEN c2;
        --for j in C2
        LOOP
            FETCH c2 INTO j;
            EXIT WHEN NOT found;

            v_text := j.product_code
                      || ','
                      || j.quantity
                      || ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,';
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE c2;

        OPEN c9('OIL');
        LOOP
            FETCH c9 INTO l;
            EXIT WHEN NOT found;
 
            v_text = v_text
                     || l.product_code
                     || ','
                     || l.terminal_code
                     || ','
                     || l.quantity
                     || ','
                     || ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,';
        END LOOP;

        v_text = v_text
                 || ',,,,,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,';
        CLOSE c9;
        raise info 'Text: %',v_text;
    END;
$procedure$;
```

How to pass multiple parameters to a cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `c9`, should PostgreSQL use the value of `p_plan_version_id` as it is in the `DECLARE` section, or as it is when you `OPEN c9`? To resolve this ambiguity, you need to pass both parameters when you open the cursor:

```
DECLARE
   c9 CURSOR (p_product_code varchar, p_pvi numeric) FOR
      SELECT product_code,
             terminal_code,
             quantity
      FROM product_stock pos
      WHERE pos.plan_version_id = p_pvi
        AND pos.product_code    = p_product_code;
BEGIN
   OPEN c9('OIL', p_plan_version_id);
   ...
END;
```

Here is a complete example to demonstrate that this works:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sample(upper_limit bigint) RETURNS SETOF bigint
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   c CURSOR (l bigint, u bigint) FOR
      SELECT * FROM generate_series(l, u) AS g(c);
   r record;
BEGIN
   OPEN c(1, upper_limit);
   LOOP
      FETCH c INTO r;
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

      RETURN NEXT r.c;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;

SELECT * FROM sample(10);

 sample 
════════
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
      6
      7
      8
      9
     10
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Hi Laurenz , Tried the same it doesn't work

Comment: Sure works, see the example I added to my answer. You must have made some mistake.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz . I had crosstab in the cursor thats why it wasn't taking the parameter. Now Issue resolved